# PKPass returns nil when initializing with the StoreCard.pass

Tags: objective-c, swift

I've tried all the possible samples StoreCard.pass but no suceess. I've tried all other type of the passes and they all work fine but the StoreCard. I am not sure what exactly I am missing. I got the sample StoreCard from Wallet Companion Files.

I appreciate your help,
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I did get an error message as the icon.png @3x is missing. In case you run into the same issue it may save you hours.